# Change model value in contructor MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

this is a technical question not a bug.

I have a model defined like this :

```
public string ModelId {get; set;}
public string OtherValue {get; set;}
```

And i have Images that are stored on server side.

I wish to make a table list of the Model with my pictures in place of the otherValue so i would like to know if it's possible and if it could be considered a good approach to change the model on the fly.
These two model are wrappers for others more complex models.

In my controller i build a model like so :

```
var data = _db.OriginalModel.Where(o => o.OriginalModelId == tempId).ToList();

var model = data.Select( d => new Model
{
    ModelId = d.OriginalModelId,
    OtherValue = d.SelectValue
});
```

Wich lead me to my question :

Can i bind data in the model with something like :

```
public Model(){
   switch(OtherValue){
        case "UP" :
         OtherValue = "pathToImage";
         break;
        case "DOWN" :
         OtherValue = "pathToImage2";
         break;
         etc...
    }
}
```

From what i have tested until now this don't work, **is there another way that is not : directly set the value of OtherValue to the path i am looking for in the select that set them?**

Comment: I can't follow your question

Comment: You are using switch `OtherValue` into integer cases? Which is then assigned a string?

Comment: Yes it may be confusing sorry i still have somes trouble with my english, no i don't use int i will edit it was for this exemple. But it don't change the question.

Comment: 99% of the time `OtherValue` will not be initialized until after the constructor.  So this really doesn't make sense.

Comment: Thank you @ErikPhilips , i know that it don't make sense but i'm trying to learn and a Class can have multiple contructor, i could pass OtherValue as argument if it was not a model, so i'm tryng to understand the best approach for this kind of things...

Answer (score 1):

Since your question is very vague and ambiguous I can only suggest that maybe you should write your logic in your Property Setter:

```
public class MyClass
{
  private string _otherValue;

  public string ModelId {get; set;}
  public string OtherValue 
  {
    get 
    {
      return this._otherValue;  
    }
    set
    {
      switch(value){
        case "UP" :
          _otherValue = "pathToImage";
          break;
        case "DOWN" :
          _otherValue = "pathToImage2";
          break;
        // etc...
      }
    }
  }    
}
```

Your title suggest changing the value in the constructor, but you have absolutely no code examples that use constructor logic with parameters.  The following are comparable:

```
var a = new MyModel();
a.ModelId = 1;
a.OtherValue = "DOWN";
```

is literally the same as:

```
var a = new MyModel
{
  ModelId = 1,
  OtherValue = "DOWN"
};
```